# Bootstrap modal window not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried today with modal windows on Bootstrap, but I have a problem. Modal won't show. I did exactly as shown in [getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) but still it isn't working. Does anybody know the problem? Here's my code.

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap scripts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Custom script as written on bootstrap page -->
<script>
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the `<script>` section? That particular script will fail because `#myModal` doesn't exist yet. It would be best to wrap your current javascript in a `$(function() { ... stuff on load goes here })` jQuery DOM-ready construct.

Comment: Bootstrap and your script requires jQuery and you didn't loaded

Comment: Can you please explain how to load it? I'm new at this. xD

Comment: go https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery and put 1.x snippet script between <head> and </head> of your code.

Comment: And yeah Cory, nothing happened. That    <script> section which I wrote because on bootstrap's page it says: "Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute has no effect in Bootstrap modals. To achieve the same effect, use some custom JavaScript - 'now that script section which I wrote.' ". I don't really know where did I go wrong. I did exactly as it needed to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so all you needed to do is add jquery to your javascript libraries as you can see below is working code just copy and paste the whole thing.  In the head of your document there is a script tag with a link to bootstraps js file and above it is a link to jquerys js file.  Bootstrap runs off of jquery so it will not work without it. With bootstrap you always need to load jquerys js file before bootstraps js file

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap scripts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Custom script as written on bootstrap page -->
<script>
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have two problems :

- First one, as @Cory said, I think you ' ld be placed your custom javascript in the bottom of your page
- Second one, you didn't include jquery (and don't forget to insert it before the bootstrap one)

I did a fiddle here and I add your `<input id="myInput" />` into your modal and it seems to work pretty well : https://jsfiddle.net/9hxo6x88/

Hope it's help

Comment: I did that also, but still :(. Then it's the problem on me. Does it matter that I use XAMPP, because I'm doing this project in PHP, and I'm hosting it on localhost?

Comment: Hi @HarisBegic, No I don't think it's your it's XAMPP the problem. 
Did you try to move your script and add jquery ? When your open your browser console, do you have a javascript error ? If yes, what is it ? And to finish what version of jquery did you include ?